# Returning a generic error-view from an area: how to use the _Layout wrapper from the controller's area?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have a `BaseController`with an errorview function, which works fine:

```
public ViewResult ErrorView(string error, string errormessage)
{
    ViewBag.ErrorType = error;
    ViewBag.ErrorMessage = errormessage;
    return View("~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml");
}
```

Extending the `BaseController` from my normal controllers and calling this function works like a charm. It wraps the view in `Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` and all is well.

However, when I call this function from a controller extending basecontroller in an area, it also wraps the view in `Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` instead of in `Areas/MyArea/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml`

How can I change this behavior without writing a separate `ErrorView` function for my area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution without code duplication

**BaseController**

```
    protected virtual string GetErrorPath()
    {
        return "~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml";
    }

    public ViewResult ErrorView(string error, string errormessage)
    {
        ViewBag.ErrorType = error;
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = errormessage;
        return View(GetErrorPath());
    }
```

**Area_BaseController : BaseController**

```
    override protected string GetErrorPath() {
        return "~/Areas/MyArea/Views/Shared/Area_Error.cshtml";
    }
```

**Area_Error.cshtml (empty wrapper)**

`@Html.Partial("Error")`

Answer (score 1):

That's the kind of problem with the areas. Since I'm not sure the framework can infer the area you're in, I would suggest something like that :

Add a AreaBaseController in your Area/Controllers folder that will setup a property witch will tell it.

In your BaseController :

```
public string Area { get; set; }

public ViewResult ErrorView(string error, string errormessage)
{
    ViewBag.ErrorType = error;
    ViewBag.ErrorMessage = errormessage;
    return View($"~/{Area}/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml");
}
```

And in that AreaBaseController :

```
public AreaBaseController()
{
    Area = "MyArea";
}
```

You might change the $"~/{Area}/ part for I didn't try it, but it should work with few changes.

Hope it help !

Comment: I ended up going with an area-specific Area_BaseController, but the implementation is still a bit different. I also ended up using an empty error view to wrap my actual error view. I will still upvote because of the idea of an area specific basecontroller, since this is what I went with